# Arcgis Esri Map: Collect pictureMarkerSymbols info on area select

Tags: javascript, json, arcgis, esri

I am trying to create a map where I can create a selection area, and get info of all graphic pointers under it, I tried to modify with following example, but they are using web service and queries, and I want it with json or array.

Thats the example http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/graphics_extent_query/ I am following

I want to get email addresses of pointers after selection. Here is a fiddle http://bit.ly/1jwLazp to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined your fiddle with the sample to produce the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/gary4620/t9h513c7/17/

```
var map;
var s;
var gl;
var highlightSymbol;

require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/toolbars/draw",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (
Map, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Draw, SimpleMarkerSymbol, InfoTemplate) {
    function initToolbar(map) {
        var tb = new Draw(map);
        tb.on("draw-end", findPointsInExtent);
        tb.activate(Draw.EXTENT);
    }

    function findPointsInExtent(result) {
        var extent = result.geometry;
        var results = [];
        require(["dojo/_base/array"], function (array) {
            array.forEach(gl.graphics, function (graphic) {
                if (extent.contains(graphic.geometry)) {
                    graphic.setSymbol(highlightSymbol);
                    results.push(graphic.getContent());
                }
                //else if point was previously highlighted, reset its symbology
                else if (graphic.symbol == highlightSymbol) {
                    graphic.setSymbol(s);
                }
            });

            //TODO use results as needed; here we just print to console
            console.log("There are " + results.length + " results:");
            console.log(results.join(""));
        });
    }

    map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "streets",
        center: [-88.21, 42.21],
        zoom: 10
    });
    map.on("load", function () {
        var content = 'email@address.com';
        gl = new GraphicsLayer();
        var p = new Point(-88.380801, 42.10560);
        s = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setSize(20);
        var g = new Graphic(p, s, {
            'title': 'Title',
            'content': content
        }, new InfoTemplate('${title}', '${content}'));
        gl.add(g);
        map.addLayer(gl);

        initToolbar(this);
    });
    highlightSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255,0,0]));
});
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for reply,

Your fiddle helped me but it only selects 1 graphic pointer, I have updated your fiddle can you please fix this issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/t9h513c7/19/

Comment: This is an interesting issue which I am also facing. Anyone have any ideas? I am also able to just get one single pin instead of all the pins in the canvas.

Comment: Danish, you are creating a new GraphicsLayer inside your jQuery loop, meaning you are creating three layers, each with one point. I moved the GraphicsLayer creation outside the jQuery loop and now it works. https://jsfiddle.net/t9h513c7/24/

Comment: Thanks @GaryS. for your help and time, I will mark it as answer now.